# Inequality for the Gamma function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, gamma-function, beta-function

Let $x,y,a,b \geq 1$. I have the feeling that the following inequality is true:
$$B(x+a,y+b)=\frac{\Gamma(x+a)\Gamma (y+b)}{\Gamma(x+y+a+b)}\leq \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}=B(x,y),$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma function and $B$ the Beta function. Nevertheless, I can not find the appropriate properties of these functions that help me conclude this.

Is there any smart idea to see this? Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may use a [classic integral representation of the Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$
\begin{align}
B(x+a,y+b)&=\int_0^1 t^{x+a-1}(1-t)^{y+b-1}dt
\\\\&\le\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt, \qquad (a\ge0,b\ge0),
\\\\&=B(x,y).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh :P of course, thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: @Martingalo You are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, a last question: can this be extended to arbitrary products? I mean: $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma\left(x_i+a_i\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)} \leq  \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma\left(x_i\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)} $. I do not see how to transfer the two-dimensional case to this one. ^^

Comment: Hmm no so direct.

Comment: I think the left-hand side is equal to $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} B(\sum_{j=1}^i x_j + a_j, x_{i+1}+a_{i+1})$ and then one can apply the estimate in each factor.

Comment: @Martingalo Karamata's inequality with the log of Gamma function would extend it.